# Mock an if/else statement with jasmine - unit testing with Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have added a minor amendment within an existing function. Our quality checks have identified this as new code therefore I need to cover the new 4 lines with a unit test - within mind there was never a unit test there to begin with and the function I added to is pretty large!

I've tried a number of ways to try and mock services, variables, spying etc... but always get errors. I'm new to jasmine so struggling. All I need to do is get any sort of check to cover the lines truthy/falsy.

**component.ts file**

```
hasDescription() {
        return this.isBrilliant() || this.isCool();
    }

isBrilliant() {
        return this.service.Type.description == 'Brilliant';
    }

isCool() {
        return this.service.Type.description == 'Cool';
    }



onExportToExcel(): void {
        var r = [];
        // added the below if/else - any check on this will be suffice.
        if (this.hasDescription()) {
            if (!this.isBrilliant()) {
                r.push('This is Cool');
            } else {
                r.push('This is Brilliant');
            }
            if (!this.isBrilliant()) {
            r.push('More Cool content');
            }
        }
}
```

I tried to set `isBrilliant(`) with a mock value of `true`, and expect that the value to be truthy `expect(component.isBrilliant()).toBeTruthy();`

I tried to set this in the spec file by:

```
const isBrilliant = true;
component.isBrilliant = isBrilliant;
```

however the error I got here was that `Type 'true' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'.`

If any experienced jasmine dev can show me a quick way to get some coverage for this simple statement that would be appreciated. Thanks

---

**UPDATE**:

I can get `isBrilliant()` to be true or false. I now need to check the array r to see if the correct string has been `.push` into it? any ideas?

Comment: Try `const isBrilliant = () => true`

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'd probably mock `service.Type.description` to be `'Brilliant'`

Comment: thanks @ShamPooSham that helped me to get past the error assigning. Can you advise on the "update"?

Comment: It will be difficult/if not impossible to get a handle on `r` in Jasmine since it is local to `onExportToExcel`. When calling `onExportToExcel`, what does it do? Does it change the view? If so, test that. Call it explicitly, and ensure it does its end product.

Comment: `onExportToExcel` doesn't seem to do anything as it is right now. Nothing is exported, no state is mutated. As AliF50 said, you should think about what you want to do with it.

Comment: @TomRudge : Please mark my answer if it helped . or let me know if you need some more inputs . Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few changes that I would suggest as a part of best practices.

1. Dont mock component method, because you need to test them. In your case, you should set value of `this.service.Type.description` and accordingly it should return `true` or `false`. That would be a correct approach.

If `this.service` is a service which has been injected on the `construtor`, you can mock the service. Refer [this article to understand mocking here](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49)

2. Since you are testing several conditions using `if` `else` , you need to write few `it` blocks to have a good test coverage.
3. To test `var r` , you should declare it as `public` variable on component level rather than inside the `function`. Also prefer `let` over `var`.

Here is a sample  code which you can write to set the value in `isBrilliant()`

```
it('should push Brilliant when the Description is so,()=>{
   component.service.Type.description = 'Brilliant';
   component.onExportToExcel();
   expect(component.r.length).toBe(1);
   expect(component.r[0]).toBe('This is Brilliant');
})

it('should push other cool content when the Description is not Brilliant,()=>{
   component.service.Type.description = 'something else';
   component.onExportToExcel();
   expect(component.r.length).toBe(2);
   // check other values in expect block accordingly
})

// you should also check that "component.r" has zero length when hasDescription() returns false
```

I hope above code snippet will give you a good start